# Autoscroll the contents in a table

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, css

I have a table inside a panel which is created dynamically using c# code. I have used this table to show news and events.My question is how can i make the contents of this table automatically scroll vertically?

Comment: Triggered by what? A time out? Click on a button?

Comment: it should trigger on page load

Comment: just use a css class on the panel and fix it's height: 100px and set overflow-y: auto? or are you meaning make the table rows scroll and not the headers that is more complex.

Comment: Yes i want the table rows to scroll

Answer (score 0):

You can do it on page load as follows:

```
$().ready(function () {
    $("table#your-table").autoscroll();
});
```

More information at [jQuery aautoscroll](http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/aautoscroll)

Comment: the scrolling effect is not coming. I am new to jquery. Can you please show how the table rows can be made to scroll automatically on page load

Comment: You need to use the selector to match our table. If you give your table an ID of `your-table`, it should work. You'll need to look at the docs to set the options though.

Comment: According to [jquery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/ready/), it's suggested to use $(document).ready(handler) or $(handler), not $().ready(handler).

Comment: @Destrictor yes the other is preferred as it's more readable $() doesn't say what it's attaching to but $(document) does

Comment: @user1692773 if you haven't fixed the height of the panel like I mentioned in the top comment it will never scroll